# Modify string in field if value in second field greater than or equal to number (in R)

Tags: r, regex, if-statement

I have a dataframe with a field containing a string of names ($LeftofEx). In a second field ($spaces.left) I have calculated the number of spaces in each string which I am using as a proxy for the number of names. What I want to do is for any string with three or more names (ie $LeftofEx ≥3) take the first name, add " & al.", and record this in a new column and also record any strings with only one or two names as is.

example input data:

```
author1 <- data.frame(LeftofEx = c('Sleepy.DW., Sneezy, D.W. Grumpy & Bashf.','Sleeping.B.','','Sneezy & D.R.Doc','','Bashf., D.R.Doc, Sneezy, Sleeping.B., W.W.Apple, Dopey & Grumpy.M.E.'),spaces.left = c(4,0,0,2,0,7))
```

Desired output:

```
 author2 <- data.frame(LeftofEx = c('Sleepy.DW., Sneezy, D.W. Grumpy & Bashf.','Sleeping.B.','','Sneezy & D.R.Doc','','Bashf., D.R.Doc, Sneezy, Sleeping.B., W.W.Apple, Dopey & Grumpy.M.E.'), spaces.left = c(4,0,0,2,0,7), curtailed = c('Sleepy.DW. & al.','Sleeping.B.','','Sneezy & D.R.Doc','','Bashf. & al.'))
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a `base r` solution:

```
author1$curtailed <- ifelse(
  author1$spaces.left > 2, 
  paste(strsplit(author1$LeftofEx, ", ")[[1]][1], "& al."), 
  author1$LeftofEx
)
author1
#>                                                               LeftofEx spaces.left
#> 1                             Sleepy.DW., Sneezy, D.W. Grumpy & Bashf.           4
#> 2                                                          Sleeping.B.           0
#> 3                                                     Sneezy & D.R.Doc           2
#> 4 Bashf., D.R.Doc, Sneezy, Sleeping.B., W.W.Apple, Dopey & Grumpy.M.E.           7
```

Comment: I'm getting "Sleepy.DW. & al." for the fourth entry as as well as the first - ie it seems to be just repeated.
Also, when I apply the script to my entire dataset all the "& al." are "NA $ al. (maybe because there are rows with blank entries for LeftofEx and 0 in the associated spaces left column? - I have updated the toy data set to reflect this).
Any ideas?